# Center Arabic/Persian/Tashkeel in a label

Tags: xcode, arabic, xcode-storyboard, persian

My label looks like this if I write a text value in English:

[image: Banana]

But like this if I paste a text value in Arabic or Persian:

[image: Banana in Arabic]

It is not using the top of the label area and falls out below. It's like the text is misaligned vertically.

I would like to fix this. What happened? Am I doing anything wrong? How do I fix it?